# Sahi keeps changing IE proxy setting

Tags: automation, sahi

So, I configured IE for sahi (as per instruction on their page) and it will work fine for a couple of script and then setting will go back to normal. 
I tried installing SSL certificates and pretty much everything else but somehow this issue is not resolving.

Any help please?

Comment: What version of Sahi are you using? Please provide some specifics of your environment.

Comment: I managed to fixed the issue simply by reinstalling everything. Thank you though.